# Knowing to interpret the phpunit tests

Tags: yii, tdd, phpunit, database-connection, fixtures

I´m trying to configure the fixtures and phpunit system is returned the next message '.E', but I don´t know how interpret it:

> C:\kyopol\Apache 2.22.22\htdocs\demo\protected\tests>**phpunit unit/EntityTest.php**
>
> PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from C:\kyopol\Apache
>   2.22.22\htdocs\demo\protected\tests\phpunit.xml
>
> **.E**
>
> Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) EntityTest::testRead Undefined variable: newEntity
>
> C:\kyopol\Apache
>   2.22.22\htdocs\demo\protected\tests\unit\EntityTest.php:37
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 2, Assertions: 3, Errors: 1.

Next, class test EntityTest.php data code:

```
class EntityTest extends CDbTestCase
{   
public function testCreate()
{
    //CREATE a new Entity
    $newEntity=new Entity;
    $newEntity->setAttributes(
        array(
                'name' => 'Test Entity 1',
                'description' => 'Test entity number one',
                'type_id' => 1,
                'location_lat' => 77,
                'location_lon' => 77,
                'create_time' => '2013-02-16 20:36:00',
                'create_user_id' => 1,
                'update_time' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                'update_user_id' => 0,
            )
    );
    $this->assertTrue($newEntity->save(false));

    //READ a Entity
    $retrievedEntity=Entity::model()->findByPk($newEntity->id);
    $this->assertTrue($retrievedEntity instanceof Entity);
    $this->assertEquals('Test Entity 1',$retrievedEntity->name);
}

public function testRead()
    {
        //READ a Entity
        $retrievedEntity=Entity::model()->findByPk($newEntity->id);
        $this->assertTrue($retrievedEntity instanceof Entity);
        $this->assertEquals('Test Entity 1',$retrievedEntity->name);
    }
}
```

What is it meaning the capital letter 'E' and the previous point '.' ?

In general: Could nobody said me how knows to interpret output messages in phpunit?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your tests is failing so that's why you see the **E**. The other one is passing, indicated by a **.**. 
If there are any error messages in the tests they will be summarized at the end.

The error message of your failing test is "Undefined variable: newEntity".

Your first line in `testRead()` is:

```
$retrievedEntity=Entity::model()->findByPk($newEntity->id);
```

But you have never setup `$newEntity` in that test.

Comment: Perfect. We have that: E: method´s error and .: method´s passed. But, would you know tell me what is 'F' capital letter. Zanks Bram.

Comment: **F** is failed. You don't have a php error or exception than, but your assertions are failing.

Comment: I know **I** for incomplete tests (you make a test incomplete by `$this->markTestIncomplete()`) and **S** for skipped tests (`$this->markTestSkipped()`). Maybe there are more, search the manual for it.

Comment: Only I found it this link, where is explained "For  each test cases when you run them ,phpunit  command line print characters to display status the status." http://www.prowareness.com/blog/unit-testing-using-phpunit-part-1/